# Export or Print Google Sheets Timeline to image\pdf

Tags: google-sheets, timeline

I have created a Timeline chart within google sheets and it looks lovely, but it does not appear that I can actually do much with it in terms of printing it or exporting it to a pdf or an image.

I would like to be able to share the timeline, for example by dropping an image into a slack channel.

I have tried a few things but

- the Print option is greyed out when on the timeline tab,
- if I export the sheet\workspace to a pdf it does not include the timeline
- The download to pdf is greyed out
- The download as webpage just has the timeline as an blank page

Is this a possibility or am I just stuck with sharing the whole worksheet which I wanted to avoid as it is not as easy to view as a straight image, especially as I have several to share?

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm facing right the same problem myself.

Comment: I have gotten nowhere with it unfortunately. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You want to save a chart as an image or PDF.

- Select the chart
- Click the `kebab` (three vertical dots in the upper right corner)
- Select `Download chart` and choose from "png", "pdf" or "svg"